# Creating a promise conditionally in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an items array that I would be getting from localStorage.

```
                   var items = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.selectedResources)['server'];

                    var arr = [];

                    var idsArray = [];

                    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                        idsArray.push(item.id);
                    });
```

Then I fire an API call ...

```
                    //Make the API call
                    ds.getBillInfo(idsArray)
                        .then(function(response){
                            var serversList = [];
                            for (var key in response) {
                                // iterate over response
```

The problem is if the items array is empty, so does the `idsArray`. 
Then the error says `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

What I want to do is `even if the idsArray is empty , I want lines to execute inside the then block thinking as there is no promise`.

How can I do that ?

**EDIT**

If I do `$q.all([ds.getBillInfo(idsArray)])` then there is no error.

The `getBillInfo()` looks like:

```
     this.getBillInfo = function(idsArray){
            if(!idsArray.length) return;
            var segmentUrl = '';
            for(var i =0;i<idsArray.length;i++){
                if(i != (idsArray.length-1))
                    segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i]+'&';
                else
                    segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i];
            }
            return HttpWrapper.send('/api/bill?bill=t&'+segmentUrl, {"operation": 'GET'});
        };
```

Comment: You need to fix `getBillInfo` to always return a promise

Comment: Something isn't right here... Like @SLaks said.

Comment: ...even returning something like `Promise.reject('empty')` would work, and you'd end up in the catch, or `Promise.resolve()` to resolve

Comment: @Pytth Please see the update, my method returns a promise.

Comment: @SLaks Please see method always returns a promise

Comment: @StrugglingCoder: No, it doesn't; otherwise, you wouldn't have a problem.  Read the very first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getBillInfo` wrap your logic with new Promise and on empty array resolve it.

Something like:

```
self.getBillInfo = function(array){

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  if(array.length == 0){
     deferred.resolve([]); // return empty list
  }
  else{
    var segmentUrl = '';
    for(var i =0;i<idsArray.length;i++){
         if(i != (idsArray.length-1))
            segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i]+'&';
         else
            segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i];
        }
       HttpWrapper.send('/api/bill?bill=t&'+segmentUrl, {"operation": 'GET'})
         .then(function (response) {
              deferred.resolve(response.data); 
         }
         , function (error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
         });

  } 

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Regards to `@JC Ford` point, since `HttpWrapper` returns Promise we can write above logic with different way as:

```
self.getBillInfo = function(array){

  if(array.length == 0){
     return $q.resolve([]); // return empty list;
  }
  else{
    var segmentUrl = '';
    for(var i =0;i<idsArray.length;i++){
         if(i != (idsArray.length-1))
            segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i]+'&';
         else
            segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i];
        }
       return HttpWrapper.send('/api/bill?bill=t&'+segmentUrl, {"operation": 'GET'});        
  } 
}
```

Comment: If `HttpWrapper.send` already returns a promise, this is redundant. It will work, but the use of `$q.defer()` is really for creating a promise when you don't already have one. This is overly complicated and thus not best practice.

Comment: @JCFord agree, but it looks clear, anyways I'll update answer with your way ;)

Answer (score 1):

inject the $q service so that it is accessible in `getBillInfo()`. You can then wrap a value in `$q.resolve()` to make a promise that returns that value. (That value could even be another promise.) So if your `getBillInfo()` function sometimes needs to return early without a value, just return an empty `$q.resolve()` instead to ensure you're always returning a promise.

```
this.getBillInfo = function(idsArray){

    //This returns undefined and causes your error.
    if(!idsArray.length) return; 

    //This returns a promise that resolves immediately and executes your .then() handler.
    if(!idsArray.length) return $q.resolve();

    //This returns a promise that rejects immediately and executes your .catch() handler
    if(!idsArray.length) return $q.reject(); 

    var segmentUrl = '';
    for(var i =0;i<idsArray.length;i++){
        if(i != (idsArray.length-1))
            segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i]+'&';
        else
            segmentUrl += 'ids='+idsArray[i];
    }
    return HttpWrapper.send('/api/bill?bill=t&'+segmentUrl, {"operation": 'GET'});
};
```

Comment: Note where you have `if(!idsArray.length) return`. Return $q.resolve() there instead.